# Как узнать кто вызвал функцию

Tags: javascript

Хочу узнать из функции которую вызвали, кто именно её вызвал, и чтобы можно было обращаться к этой функции и к её prototype.

```
let useState = val => {
 // как узнать здесь кто вызвал функцию?
}

function test(){
  useState(123)
}
```

такие методы как Function.caller не подходят, ибо очень старые. Как можно по новому узнать кто вызвал функцию.

Comment: никак нельзя узнать.

Comment: и что в таком случае посоветуете делать?

Comment: Добавить ещё параметр и определять через него. Это js количество параметров ограничено только вашей фантазией.

Comment: Может зависеть от цели. Можно решать в лоб и руками вторым параметром передавать кто вызывает. Можно кидать ошибку и разбирать строку стектрейса. Но в большинстве случаев ничего подобного не нужно. Поэтому стоит добавить _зачем_ нужно знать кто вызвал функцию

Comment: Объясните что вы хотите делать, какую задачу решаете и почему решили, что узнать кто вызвал функцию это решение вашей задачи. Скорее всего, вам могут помочь решить вашу задачу намного эффективнее

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, надёжного способа нет.

[`Function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) не рекомендовано к использованию.

Можно попробовать распарсить стек, но это тоже будет хрупкий костыль на костыле:

```js
let useState = val => {
  const callerName = new Error().stack.split('\n')[2].split(/\s+/)[2];
  console.log(eval(callerName).prototype);
}

function test() {
  useState(123);
}

test.prototype.foo = 42;

test(); // { foo: 42 }
```

Так что вам лучше предусмотреть в вашем API какой-то явный способ передавать информацию о контексте вызова.

Comment: `caller` не то чтобы не рекомендован, он просто не будет работать в strict mode например.

Comment: и `eval` тоже не всегда сработает, лучше указать, что максимум строку с именем можно получить, причем иногда можно и ее не получить

Comment: Ну, под костылём на костыле это и подразумевалось, что любая стадия ненадёжна)

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, распарсив `(new Error).stack`.

```js
function getStack(сколькоПропустить = 1){
  const регуляркаАнонима = /^at (\S+) \(<anonymous>\)$/,
        регуляркаФункции = /^at (\S+) \(([^:]+):([^:]+):(\d+):(\d+)\)$/,
        регуляркаФайла = /^at ([^:]+):([^:]+):(\d+):(\d+)$/;
  return (new Error).stack
    .split(/\n/g)
    .filter((строка,номер) => номер > сколькоПропустить)
    .map(строка => строка.trim())
    .map(строка => регуляркаАнонима.exec(строка)|| 
                   регуляркаФункции.exec(строка)||
                   регуляркаФайла.exec(строка))
    .map(результат => 
      результат.length < 3 ? 
        { функция: результат[1] } : 
      результат.length > 5 ? 
        { функция: результат[1], 
          файл:    `${результат[2]}:${результат[3]}`,
          строка:  результат[4],
          символ:  результат[5]} :
        { файл:    `${результат[1]}:${результат[2]}`,
          строка:  результат[3],
          символ:  результат[4]}
    );
}

const prototypeflag = Symbol('true');

iAmCallingThatFunction.prototype = {
  [prototypeflag]: true
};

function whoCallsMe(){
  const стэк = getStack(2);
  console.log('стэк', стэк);
  const функция = findFunctionWithNeededPrototype(стэк);
  console.log('функция', функция);
  const прототип = функция.prototype;
  console.log('нужный прототип?',прототип[prototypeflag]);
}

function iAmCallingThatFunction(){
  whoCallsMe();
}

iAmCallingThatFunction();

var Массив = class extends Array {
  get [prototypeflag](){ return !0; }
  methodThatCallsFunction(){
    this.forEach(function() {
      whoCallsMe();
    });
    this.forEach(whoCallsMe);
  }
}
const массив = new Массив(1).fill(0);
массив.methodThatCallsFunction();

function findFunctionWithNeededPrototype(стэк){
  for(let индекс = 0; индекс < стэк.length; индекс++){
    let имя = стэк[индекс].функция;
    if(!имя) continue;
    if(/\./.test(имя))
      имя = имя.replace(/\..*$/,'');
    if(имя && 'function' == typeof window[имя] &&
        window[имя].prototype[prototypeflag])
      return window[имя];
  }
  throw new Error('Неправильная функция');
}
```

Comment: `window[стэк[0].функция]` - вот так делать не стоит, если не уверен, что функция точно глобавльная

Comment: @Grundy Можно иметь свой объект со всеми функциями по такому случаю. А здесь `window` для упрощения понимания алгоритма функции.

Comment: нельзя, так как нельзя гарантировать, что все функции будут в этом объекте, да и запихивать все в один объект, обычно не нужно

Comment: @Grundy но мы не знаем какой у автора функционал, может ему нужно и сделает... все функции в один объект запихивать не нужно, а интересующие функции, откуда может вызываться заветная функция, можно разместить куда-нибудь типа `window`

Comment: Даже в этом случае нельзя гарантировать, так как вызываемая функция может являться методом объекта, например `forEach`

Comment: @Grundy Так stacktrace показывает не только сам метод, но и его объект и его класс и где он был создан.

Comment: @Grundy Для этого собственно и был внедрен параметр `сколькоПропустить` чтобы отсеять гарантировано ненужное кол-во строк stacktrace.

Comment: и как это тут поможет?:)

Comment: @Grundy в ответ на ваш вопрос в комментарии выше добавил немного кода в ответ.

Comment: sidenote: если уж пишешь имена переменных по-русски, старайся, чтобы по имени можно было понять, что делает функция, либо для чего нужна переменная.

Comment: @Grundy, суть в том, что функцию `ктоМеняВызывал()` вызываю три раза различными способами. Во всех трех случаях функция находит нужный прототип. Какие из функций или переменных названы непонятно?

Comment: _Какие из функций или переменных названы непонятно_: `const тру`, `дайСтэк`, `методВедетСебяВызывающе`, `найдиФукциюИмеющуюТрушныйПрототип`

Comment: @Grundy, вот так должно быть понятнее.

Comment: Понятнее, но не сильно, не важно на каком языке идентификатор, главное, чтобы в нем смысл был.

Comment: В любом случае остаются как минимум две проблемы: не все функции объявлены в глобальной переменной и даже те, которые объявлены могут иметь собственное имя отличное от имени поля в глобальном объекте.

Comment: @Grundy я думаю, у автора ограниченное количество таких функций, и скорее всего они лежат в одном namespace, который не window, и вероятнее всего, там не будет проблем с именами. В противном случае есть вариант опираться на **файл:строка:символ**, правда там придётся AST парсить/перебирать.